# Insert value into table from another table mybatis xml

Tags: postgresql, mybatis

I'd like to know if i need to return value after first INSERT then pass it to next INSERT or i can just use this kind of code

```
<insert id="CreateUser" parameterType="com.portale.model.UserObject">
        INSERT INTO users(user_org, user_login, user_pass, locked)
        VALUES (#{organization},#{username},#{password},#{locked})
        INSERT INTO users_details(details_id, nome, cognome)
        VALUES ((SELECT users.user_id FROM users WHERE user_login = #{username}),#{nome},#{cognome})
</insert>
```

This code give me an error

```
### Error updating database.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "INSERT") Позиция: 87
### The error may exist in file [D:\Users\Eclipse and VM\Tomcat\apache-tomcat- 8.5.53\wtpwebapps\com.portale\WEB-INF\classes\com\portale\mapper\UserMapper.xml]
### The error may involve com.portale.mapper.UserMapper.CreateUser-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: INSERT INTO users(user_org, user_login, user_pass, locked)    VALUES (?,?,?,?)    INSERT INTO users_details(details_id, nome, cognome)    VALUES ((SELECT users.user_id FROM users WHERE user_login = ?),?,?)
### Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "INSERT") Позиция: 87;
bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "INSERT") Позиция: 87!!!! Exception cause!!!! org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: "INSERT") Позиция: 87
```

But all parameters are passed in the code.
Can i use (SELECT...) with (INSERT) in MyBatis ? Is this an wrong way to do it or a issue by passing parameters?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a simple ";" missing.
After first query (INSERT) of course sql need to know that the next INSERT is a new query so after writing the first one you need to put an ";"

```
<insert id="CreateUser" parameterType="com.portale.model.UserObject">
    INSERT INTO users(user_org, user_login, user_pass, locked)
    VALUES (#{organization},#{username},#{password},#{locked});
    INSERT INTO users_details(details_id, nome, cognome)
    VALUES ((SELECT users.user_id FROM users WHERE user_login = #{username}),#{nome},#{cognome})
</insert>
```